# discord.js DM command not direct messaging mentioned users

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I was making my discord bot, I came to another problem. Now I am making a command that should DM a person that is mentioned in bot commands channel. But I can't make it to work. I tried a lot of things but they don't seem to work. If someone can help me that help will be really appreciated Here is my code for a DM command:

```
module.exports = {
    name:'dm',
    description: 'dm mentioned user',
    execute(message, args){
        const user = message.mentions.users.first()

        user.send('test command');
        
        
        
    }
}
```

and this is my code in main file:

```
if(command === 'dm'){
        client.commands.get('dm').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message? Is there a typo too? There was a missing `'` here: `user.send('test command')`

Comment: I accidenatly deleted '  while copying code and in terminal i dont get any error message

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to fetch the user first:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'dm',
  description: 'dm mentioned user',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const user = await message.mentions.users.first().fetch();
    const channel = await user.createDM();

    channel.send('test command');
  },
};
```

Comment: That didnt seem to fix the issue it still doesnt dm the person but thanks for help anyways.

Comment: Oh, and what if you create a DM channel? I've updated my code above.

Comment: That didnt seem to work either i created channel called dm and nothing happend when i typed command

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reasons, my first guess is that you can only DM members, not users

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first()
user.send('test command');
```

My other guess is that the person you're trying to DM does not allow DMs from strangers.